# Calendar gets saved successfully.but edit event force close error

Tags: android, eclipse, calendar

I am trying to add calendar events with my Android applicatiom. Event gets saved successfully. However when i try to edit that event in Calendar. I get Force Close error.

```
       String calId = "";
        Cursor userCursor =getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(content://com.android.calendar/calendars),null, null, null, null);
        if(userCursor.getCount() > 0){
            userCursor.moveToFirst();
            calId = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            }
        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
        event.put("title", "title");
        event.put("description", "description");
        event.put("eventLocation", "Event Location");
        event.put("allDay", 0);
        event.put("hasAlarm",0);
        event.put("calendar_id",calId);
        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mCalendar.set(2012, 2, 27,7,00,00);
        long start = mCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
        mCalendar.set(2012, 2, 27,8,00,00);
        long end = mCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
        event.put("dtstart",  start);
        event.put("dtend", end);


        Uri newEvent = Uri.parse(content://com.android.calendar/events);
        getContentResolver().insert(newEvent, event);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        userCursor.close();
```

But when I change event.put("allDay", 0); to event.put("allDay", 1);
Event gets saved successfully and gets edited successfully.

How do I fix it?

Using 2.3.5 device. Appreciate any help. thanks.

Log?you mean this?

```
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.EditEvent}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.java:286)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at com.android.calendar.TimezoneAdapter.showInitialTimezones(TimezoneAdapter.java:255)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at com.android.calendar.TimezoneAdapter.<init>(TimezoneAdapter.java:198)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at com.android.calendar.EditEvent.init(EditEvent.java:755)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at com.android.calendar.EditEvent.onCreate(EditEvent.java:675)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     ... 11 more
03-25 23:13:00.160: W/ActivityManager(245):   Force finishing activity com.android.calendar/.EditEvent
03-25 23:13:00.670: W/ActivityManager(245): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{2b47e518 com.android.calendar/.EditEvent}
```

Comment: Attach log showing FC and possibly code for creating the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I successfully edit event.

```
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 23:13:00.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7432): at java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.java:286)
```

It did not set the timezone.

So it only need to join one line

```
    event.put("eventTimezone", Time.getCurrentTimezone());
```

The event could be edited correctly.